# Creating composite primary key consisting off foreign keys in fluent API with ASP.NET core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

The question here is how can i generate a composite primary key consisting of two foreign keys?

I have tried:

```
public class ActiveQuestions_Questions 
{
    [Column(Order = 0), Key, ForeignKey("ActiveQuestion")]
    public string ActiveQuestionId {get; set;}

    [Column(Order = 1), Key, ForeignKey("Question")]
    public string QuestionId {get; set; }
}
```

Which gives me: Entity type 'ActiveQuestions_Questions' has composite primary key defined with data annotations. To set composite primary key, use fluent API.

Then i tried using the fluent api in the model builder without the annotations.

```
builder.Entity<ActiveQuestions_Questions>(
            build => 
            {
                build.HasKey(t => new {t.ActiveQuestionId, t.QuestionId}); 
                build.HasOne(t => t.QuestionId).WithOne().HasForeignKey<Question>(qe => qe.QuestionId);
                build.HasOne(t => t.ActiveQuestionId).WithOne().HasForeignKey<ActiveQuestion>(qe => qe.ActivateQuestionId); 
            }
        );
```

Which gave me : 
The navigation property 'QuestionId' cannot be added to the entity type 'ActiveQuestions_Questions' because a property with the same name already exists on entity type 'ActiveQuestions_Questions'.

Anyone that can point me in the right direction?

The Questions class

```
public class Question 
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public string QuestionId {get; set;}

    [Required]
    public string Text {get; set;}
}
```

The ActiveQuestion class:

```
public class ActiveQuestion 
{
    private DateTime _lastUpdated = DateTime.Now; 

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public string ActivateQuestionId {get; set;}

    public DateTime LastUpdated 
    {
        get 
        {
            return this._lastUpdated; 
        }
        set 
        {
            this._lastUpdated = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant portion of the `Question` and `ActiveQuestion` entities (at least containing the PK properties and `ActiveQuestions_Questions` related navigation properties)

Comment: @IvanStoev Added the Question and ActiveQuestion classes.

Comment: Thank you. I think the currently posted answer is covering the case. In case it's not clear, the PK fluent configuration is correct, but both FK are not. `build.HasOne(t => t.QuestionId)` should be `build.HasOne<Qustion>()` and  `build.HasOne(t => t.ActiveQuestionId)` should be `build.HasOne<ActiveQuestion>()` to reflect the lack of the navigation property in your entity classes.

Comment: Thanks @IvanStoev :)

Answer (score 14):

In EF Core, defining composite PK using `KeyAttribute` is not supported, therefore you must use fluent API to configure composite PK.

```
build.HasKey(t => new {t.ActiveQuestionId, t.QuestionId});
```

Above syntax you used in your code is correct way to define composite PK. For more information see [Keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys) in docs.

The reason your code fails is the incorrect configuration of relationship. `HasOne`/`WithOne` API are supposed to be used with navigation properties (properties which targets other entity types). In your configuration you are passing a primitive property in `HasOne` call. Since there is already property with same name added in the model (through conventions & `HasKey` call), it throws above exception. Even if they hadn't been added, there would be different exception. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships) is the link to docs on how to define relationships using fluent API.